# C# Winforms Transparent Control allowing Clickthrough

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, transparency

I have a Winforms control that starts off completely transparent, but then lines are drawn on it for stuff. I want mouse events to completely ignore the control and instead go to the stuff (buttons and all that junk) below.

Is there any way to do this? P/Invoking stuff would be fine, by the way.

Comment: If it helps, I'm trying to draw an overlay on top of a Flash control in my forum (using the COM Flash control.)

Comment: I was looking for something similar and I've found this answer that works form me http://stackoverflow.com/a/4691889/1057961

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a solution to this too. The closest i've come is getting the completely transparent areas to have click-through, by **setting the control's Region property** to the transparent area. (courtesy of this post: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/815914-transparent-user-control-click-through-control-below#post3251154)