# C# Winforms Transparent Control allowing Clickthrough

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency, panel, mouseevent

I have a problem, a bit related to:
[C# Winforms Transparent Control allowing Clickthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855826/c-winforms-transparent-control-allowing-clickthrough)

Contrary to him I would like to capture mouse events on my program, while still retaining a "window" to whats behind my program.
color.transparent doesn't work, and transparency key just delivers mouse events to whatever is underneath.
Using a panel with transparent BackColor or with a BackColor equal to transparency key does not give the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture the mouse events, and that's include the `MouseClick`, then simply use transparency, but don't set it to `0` set it to `1`.

It will be transparent enough to see through, but because it's non-zero the mouse events will be processed the the front-most window.

Comment: This makes any controls you might want to show on the form with transparency - also transparent.