# C# How to set Transparent key and do not allow click-through?

Tags: c#, transparency

Well, I know how to set the transparent key,

but if i click the transparent region, it clicks through the form.
is it possible to disabling click through?

hmm.. I think this question is similar as 
[C# Winforms Transparent Control allowing Clickthrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547425/c-sharp-winforms-transparent-control-allowing-clickthrough)

but i do not understand the answer, what value should i change to 1???

Comment: Why are you trying to confuse the user?  She can see something to click on, whatever is underneath your window.  But clicking on it won't work?  The answer is no.  Although it got pretty broken in Aero.

Answer (score 0):

`Opacity`. Which controls general transparency of the form and it's only see-through, not click-through (unless `0` is used).

However, your form will be (very faintly) visible using that method.

It's a bit more complex to make only a region of the form transparent this way, though.

Comment: hmm.. I forgot about the Opacity property.. Thank you for reminding me. I cannot create the effect that I wanted with this property, but I can make the similar one.